# Food Ordering System UML Class Diagram

Tags: oop, uml, computer-science, diagram, class-diagram

I am trying to create a food ordering system for my homework. I learnt terminolgy which like aggregation,composition,inheritance etc. But when i trying to build diagram im confusing about how i need to design.

For beginning i created some classes:

- User
- Customer
- Vendor
- Restaurant
- Food
- Order
- Order Details
- Shipping Info
- Shopping Cart
- Payment

[image]

I linked some of them but it got worse as it continued.

Is there any suggestion how i design this or what my mindset has to be ?

(Note: I don't need any coding. Just diagram drawing.)

Comment: Simple things melt down to a few classes. Complex things need more. That's just live. If you go into details (maybe looking at the restaurant employees health insurance) you get even more details. Try to focus.

Comment: @bruno It's correct, but it does not really address the OP's question _"how i design this"_ (which I voted to close).

Answer (score 2):

You use too much the composition, this kind of relation is very strong, for instance having `vendor <*>---restaurant` means when the vendor disappears (dies) the restaurant disappears too, which is wrong

In your case the compositions are not even aggregations, for instance the shopping card is not a part of a customer except if it is tattooed on him ;-)

The inheritances between *order details* and *shipping info* with *order* is wrong, *A inherits B* means *A* is a *B*., Note you can have the composition `order <*>---- order details` supposing the class *order details* has a sense.

*payment method* can be used in class-associations between a customer and the restaurant.

You can specify the multiplicities in your relations, and all of them do not bidirectional.

I encourage you to name the classes with an uppercase character at the beginning of each word (*OrderDetail* etc)

(You have some free UML tools to avoid to use a pencil)